# Multivariant email in Dynamics CRM

Tags: email, dynamics-crm

Does anybody have resources on multivariant email testing in Dynamics CRM? 
Multivariant email being where an organization wants to segment their contacts and send separant variations of an email campaign to different segments in their organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a marketing campaign and segment the people out by Marketing Lists.  Then create specific campaign activities for each marketing list that is added to the campaign.

Answer (score 1):

Like Focus is saying Marketing Campaign is the solution.

If you want resources on the Marketing portion of CRM take a look at

http://www.redware.com/mscrm/ms_crm_handbook/microsoft_crm_marketing.html

It contains all explainations on how to create and distribute email campaigns.